# Avoiding non-centered caption on ctable with float

Tags: floats, captions, ctable

I try to put my floats under the control of KOMA-Script using `\restylefloat` and KOMA's `komaabove` and `komabelow`. This works, but gives undesired side effects with `ctable`. The tables are centered but their captions are flush left.

How can I correct this?

**Edit:** I want both the caption and the table to be centered.

[image: ctable-koma-float-bug]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ctable}
\floatstyle{komaabove}
\restylefloat{table}
\begin{document}
\ctable[table,caption={Test test test test testtest test test testtest},
label=tbl:things]%
{>{}p{.4\linewidth}@{}c}{}{%
\FL Part           & done
\ML Title          & yes
\NN Intro          & yes
\NN Solution       & yes
\NN Implementation & yes
\NN Evaluation     & no
\NN Related Work   & no
\NN Conclusion     & yes
\LL
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit2:** I found this is not KOMA-Script specific, this non-KOMA MWE exihibits similar behavior

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ctable}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\restylefloat{table}
\begin{document}
\ctable[table,caption={Test test test test testtest test test testtest},
label=tbl:things]%
{>{}p{.4\linewidth}@{}c}{}{%
\FL Part           & done
\ML Title          & yes
\NN Intro          & yes
\NN Solution       & yes
\NN Implementation & yes
\NN Evaluation     & no
\NN Related Work   & no
\NN Conclusion     & yes
\LL
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please insert code using the brackets symbol, otherwise we can't copy it properly.

If you wish to align caption and table, just add "left":

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{ctable} 
\floatstyle{komaabove}
 \restylefloat{table} 
\begin{document}
\ctable[table,caption={Test test test test testtest test test
  testtest}, label=tbl:things, left]%
{>{}p{.4\linewidth}@{}c}{} {%
 \FL Part & done 
 \ML Title & yes 
 \NN Intro  & yes 
 \NN Solution & yes 
 \NN Implementation & yes 
 \NN Evaluation & no 
 \NN Related Work & no 
 \NN Conclusion & yes 
 \LL 
} 
\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT**

I guess there is a bug somewhere, but whether it is in ctable or somewhere in KOMAscript, who knows? Due to this, you can't get the table and the caption centered.

Maybe -- and if you really are convinced to need ctable -- you ask the maintainer of KOMAscript: www.komascript.de

Comment: Thanks for the formatting suggestion. I clarified my question. I want all things centered here.

Comment: Then you are in trouble. But this isn't worth the time and effort, simply swap ctable against a tabular environment and go ahead.

Comment: Well, I am making a class and do not want to restrict my users too much.

Comment: Asking the KOMA maintainer turned up that it is not a KOMA problem at all. It seems to be a float/ctable bug.

Comment: Note: I accept this as this post first indicated a non-user-fixable bug.

Answer (score 2):

I get the desired result if I use the KOMA-option `captions=tableheading` and remove both `\floatstyle{komaabove}` and `\restylefloat{table}` and also `\usepackage{float}`.

```
\documentclass[captions=tableheading]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{ctable} 

\begin{document}
\ctable[
    table,
    caption={Test test test test testtest test test testtest},
    label=tbl:things
  ]{>{}p{.4\linewidth}@{}c}{} {%
     \FL Part & done 
     \ML Title & yes 
     \NN Intro  & yes 
     \NN Solution & yes 
     \NN Implementation & yes 
     \NN Evaluation & no 
     \NN Related Work & no 
     \NN Conclusion & yes 
     \LL 
} 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I meant question however specifically for when I use `\restylefloat`. The reason is that (since I write a class) I want my users to be able to use normal tables as well as `ctable`s, and, in both cases, the caption end up _above_ the table, regardless of whether the `\caption` is (in the code) given before or after the `tabular`.

Answer (score 2):

With `threeparttable` and `booktabs` it works flawlessly

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Test test test test testtest test test testtest}
\label{tbl:things}
\begin{tabular}{p{.4\linewidth}@{}c}
\toprule
Part           & done \\
\midrule
Title          & yes \\
Intro          & yes \\
Solution       & yes \\
Implementation & yes \\
Evaluation     & no  \\
Related Work   & no  \\
Conclusion     & yes \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good to know! Since I write a wrapper class, I however have to care for the case when it is actually a `ctable`. Any idea?

Comment: @Tobias Sorry, no; I've never considered `ctable` among my preferred packages.

Comment: Me no longer, I think...